# Refresh Control stops working if listView goes offscreen

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to receive an list of items from firebase, including an image, which will be rendered in a list.

The problem is, when the list gets too big an fall of the screen, the Refresh Control stops working.

[Working way, with the list full on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MQap.png)

[Not working, if pulled, makes this effect of "reached on max"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2vcb.png)

---

### Render method

```
<View contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ListView
      enableEmptySections
      dataSource={this.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
      }
    />
  </View>
```

---

```
onRefresh() {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true });
    this.props.eventsFetch();
  }
```